# how to replace unicode substring with new unicode

Tags: python, unicode, hebrew

I have files in Biblical Hebrew with older Unicodes that I want to upgrade to the new special unicodes. I'm working in Python.

For a specific example, in Unicode the following concatenated Unicodes -- '\u05d9' + '\u05b4' -- give bet with dagesh בּ. However, there is a new Unicode -- '\ufb31' -- which specifically gives bet with dagesh only in a better placement.

I'm trying to loop through a file and every time I find a deprecated version of a Hebrew character to then replace it with the updated character. I tried using a dictionary, but this does not work with str.replace(). The following is the code:

```
hebrew_unicodes_dict = {
'\u05d9' + '\u05b4': '\ufb1d', ## yod with hiriq
'\u05E9' + '\u05c1': '\ufb2a', ## shin with shin dot
'\u05E9' + '\u05c2': '\ufb2b', ## shin with sin dot
'\ufb49' + '\u05c1': '\ufb2c', ## shin with dagesh and shin dot
'\ufb49' + '\u05c2': '\ufb2d', ## shin with dagesh and sin dot
'\u05d0' + '\u05b7': '\ufb2e', ## alef with patach
'\u05d0' + '\u05b8': '\ufb2f', ## alef with qamats
'\u05d0' + '\u05bc': '\ufb30', ## alef with mappiq
'\u05d1' + '\u05bc': '\ufb31', ## bet with dagesh
'\u05d2' + '\u05bc': '\ufb32', ## gimel with dagesh
'\u05d3' + '\u05bc': '\ufb33', ## dalet with dagesh
'\u05d4' + '\u05bc': '\ufb34', ## he with mappiq
'\u05d5' + '\u05bc': '\ufb35', ## vav with dagesh (shuruq)
'\u05d6' + '\u05bc': '\ufb36', ## zayin with dagesh
'\u05d8' + '\u05bc': '\ufb38', ## tet with dagesh
'\u05d9' + '\u05bc': '\ufb39', ## yod with dagesh
'\u05da' + '\u05bc': '\ufb3a', ## final kaf with dagesh
'\u05db' + '\u05bc': '\ufb3b', ## kaf with dagesh
'\u05dc' + '\u05bc': '\ufb3c', ## lamed with dagesh
'\u05de' + '\u05bc': '\ufb3e', ## mem with dagesh
'\u05e0' + '\u05bc': '\ufb40', ## nun with dagesh
'\u05e1' + '\u05bc': '\ufb41', ## samekh with dagesh
'\u05e3' + '\u05bc': '\ufb43', ## final pe with dagesh
'\u05e6' + '\u05bc': '\ufb46', ## tsadi with dagesh
'\u05e7' + '\u05bc': '\ufb47', ## qof with dagesh
'\u05e8' + '\u05bc': '\ufb48', ## resh with dagesh
'\u05e9' + '\u05bc': '\ufb49', ## shin with dagesh
'\u05ea' + '\u05bc': '\ufb4a', ## tav with dagesh
'\u05d5' + '\u05b9': '\ufb4b', ## holam vav
'\u05d1' + '\u05bf': '\ufb4c', ## vet with rafe
'\u05db' + '\u05bf': '\ufb4d', ## khaf with rafe
'\u05e4' + '\u05bf': '\ufb4e', ## fe with rafe
'\u05d0' + '\u05dc': '\ufb4f'  ## alef lamed ligature
}

print('length of Hebrew_unicodes_dict is ' +       str(len(hebrew_unicodes_dict)))
## print('printing hebrew_unicodes_dict')
## print(hebrew_unicodes_dict)
### This script replaces deprecated unicodes for Hebrew letters with the more updated unicodes.

torah_file = open     ('/users/alberthembd/Desktop/Ginsburg_Source/01_Genesis.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
revised_torah_file =     open('/Users/alberthembd/Documents/PythonDocuments/01_Genesis_fixed.txt', 'w')

with torah_file, revised_torah_file:
         for line in torah_file:
         for old_value, new_value in (hebrew_unicodes_dict.items()):
                 old_line = line
                 print('line before' + line)
                 line.replace(old_value, new_value)
                 new_line = line
                 print('new_line == ' + new_line)
                 print('new line == old_line ' + new_line == old_line)
             revised_torah_file.write(line)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that it is difficult to access the right unicode from the above dictionary, seeing as one cannot simply name that key precisly.

My apologies! I am a beginner!

Comment: The code writes to the revised_torah_file OK. But line.replace() does not replace the old unicode substring with the new single unicode.

Comment: The older characters are *not deprecated*. You are trying to replace *combining* characters with *precomposed* ones, which is valid, but it's also valid to use them as is. There are good reasons to stick with one form or another; the conversion is called [*normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) and that functionality [is built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Comment: P.S. After I finish my stint as a compiler of Bible editions, I would <b> love</b> to work as a Python developer!

Comment: "But line.replace() does not replace the old unicode substring with the new single unicode." Yes, it does - *in a new string*, which your code ignores.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum; your future aspirations are off topic.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Karl, for your speedy reply! Here's the reason I want to do the conversion. I need to compare my files to a better electronic edition of the Hebrew Bible, and that better edition uses the "precomposed" unicodes. So it's either convert that file, or the existing files I have. Because there are differences in vowel points, accents, and even letters between the two editions, and I have to identify them.

Comment: Dear Karl:

""But line.replace() does not replace the old unicode substring with the new single unicode." Yes, it does - in a new string, which your code ignores. –"

AAAAHHHHHH! Thanks so so much! So I need to assign the result to a new string!

Al